# Unexpected case behaviour in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a wrong value in a very simple piece (as I thought) of code:

```
org = 4
case org
when org <= 1
  val = 'L'
when 2..3
  val = 'M'
when org >= 4
  val = 'H'
end

puts val
=> nil
```

Please, don't be angry, I expect that I missed something very obvious, but I really can't figure it out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic Ruby blunder. `case` has two methods of being called, one where you pass in a thing to branch based on, and one where you don't.

If you *do* specify an expression in the `case` statement then all the other conditions are evaluated and compared with `===`. In this case `org <= 1` evaluates down to `false` and `org === false` is obviously not true. The same goes for all other cases, they're either true or false. That means none of them match.

If you don't specify an expression then `case` behaves like a fancy `if`.

Switch `case org` to `case` and it works. You can also switch to ranges:

```
val =
  case org
  when 0..1
    'L'
  when 2..3
    'M'
  else
    'H'
  end
```

The way your original code executes is as if it were:

```
org = 4
if (org <= 1) === org
  val = 'L'
elsif (2..3) === org
  val = 'M'
elsif (org >= 4) === org
  val = 'H'
end
```

Which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you man, it works!!!!!
if you''ll be so kind - put my nose into piece of documentation that will clarify this for me.

Comment: @S.ork From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case): "The first when clause to match the condition (or to evaluate to Boolean truth, if the condition is null) “wins”, and its code stanza is executed"

Comment: @AndrewPiliser this doesn't help, in my case only third clause evaluated to true, but it never execute.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Try to link through to the current version of the docs whenever possible. That's a 1.9 link.

Comment: The [official docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) do cover it, though not as in-depth as they probably should. I've added some code here that shows how your example is interpreted.

Comment: I never though about how the OP's code would be interpreted. Thanks

Comment: So one stupid solution would be to replace `case org` by `case true` :D

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could write:

```
letters = %w(L L M M H)
val = letters[org.clamp(0,4)]
```

It uses [`Comparable#clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp), which comes with Ruby 2.4.

For Ruby 2.3 and older, you can use :

```
val = letters[[0, org, 4].sort[1]]
```

This way, it's fine if `org` is smaller than `0` or larger than `4`.